Oracle REGEXP_SUBSTR for splitting string to multiple columns using length and space delimiter
Experts , Trying to split the lengthy test into multiple columns of 30 char length also wanted to consider space, i.e. do not want to break the word , if the 30th position is a letter wanted to go back to the previous space and break, wanted to repeat this until the end of the full text length
For example
For Heaven only knows why anyone loves it so, how one sees it so, making it up, building it round one, tumbling it, creating it every moment afresh
should come as separate columns as



Value
Column Name




For Heaven only knows why
FIRST30


anyone loves it so, how one --length 27
SECOND30


sees it so, making it up,
THIRD30


building it round one,
FOURTH30



but it is coming as



Value
Column Name




For Heaven only knows why
FIRST30


anyone loves it so, how one sees --length 32
SECOND30


it so, making it up, building
THIRD30


it round one, tumbling it,
FOURTH30



Please suggest a fix or any better approach. Appreciate your inputs.
with spaces as (
 select regexp_instr('For Heaven only knows why anyone loves it so, how one sees it so, making it up, building it round one, tumbling it, creating it every moment afresh' || ' '
                    , '[[:space:]]', 1, level) as s
   from dual
connect by level <= regexp_count('For Heaven only knows why anyone loves it so, how one sees it so, making it up, building it round one, tumbling it, creating it every moment afresh' || ' '
                                , '[[:space:]]')
        )
, SPLITTED as (
 SELECT MAX(case when s <= 30 then s else 0 end) as a
      , max(case when s <= 60 then s else 0 end) as b
      , max(case when s <= 90 then s else 0 end) as c
      , max(case when s <= 120 then s else 0 end) as d
   from spaces
        )
select Trim(substr('For Heaven only knows why anyone loves it so, how one sees it so, making it up, building it round one, tumbling it, creating it every moment afresh',1,a)) AS FIRST30
     , Trim(substr('For Heaven only knows why anyone loves it so, how one sees it so, making it up, building it round one, tumbling it, creating it every moment afresh',a, b - a))  AS SECOND30
     , Trim(substr('For Heaven only knows why anyone loves it so, how one sees it so, making it up, building it round one, tumbling it, creating it every moment afresh',b, c - b)) AS THIRD30
     , Trim(substr('For Heaven only knows why anyone loves it so, how one sees it so, making it up, building it round one, tumbling it, creating it every moment afresh',c, d - c)) AS FOURTH30
  FROM SPLITTED


You can use a recursive query to split the text:
WITH data (id, value) AS (
  SELECT id,
         value || ' '
  FROM   table_name
),
find (id, value, lvl, epos, text) AS (
  SELECT id,
         value,
         1,
         CASE
         WHEN INSTR(SUBSTR(value, 1, 31), ' ', -1) >= 1
         THEN 1 + INSTR(SUBSTR(value, 1, 31), ' ', -1)
         ELSE -1
         END,
         CASE
         WHEN INSTR(SUBSTR(value, 1, 31), ' ', -1) >= 1
         THEN SUBSTR(value, 1, INSTR(SUBSTR(value, 1, 31), ' ', -1) - 1)
         ELSE NULL
         END
  FROM   data
UNION ALL
  SELECT id,
         value,
         lvl + 1,
         CASE
         WHEN INSTR(SUBSTR(value, epos, 31), ' ', -1) >= 1
         THEN epos + INSTR(SUBSTR(value, epos, 31), ' ', -1)
         ELSE -1
         END,
         CASE
         WHEN INSTR(SUBSTR(value, epos, 31), ' ', -1) >= 1
         THEN SUBSTR(value, epos, INSTR(SUBSTR(value, epos, 31), ' ', -1) - 1)
         ELSE NULL
         END
  FROM   find
  WHERE  epos > -1
)
SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY id SET order_id
SELECT id, text, lvl
FROM   find
WHERE  text IS NOT NULL;

or, with regular expressions (which may be slower):
WITH data (id, value) AS (
  SELECT id,
         value || ' '
  FROM   table_name
),
find (id, value, lvl, epos, text) AS (
  SELECT id,
         value,
         1,
         REGEXP_INSTR(value, '(.{0,30}) ', 1, 1, 1),
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, '(.{0,30}) ', 1, 1, NULL, 1)
  FROM   data
UNION ALL
  SELECT id,
         value,
         lvl + 1,
         REGEXP_INSTR(value, '(.{0,30}) ', epos, 1, 1),
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, '(.{0,30}) ', epos, 1, NULL, 1)
  FROM   find
  WHERE  epos > 0
)
SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY id SET order_id
SELECT id, text, lvl
FROM   find
WHERE  text IS NOT NULL;

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (id, value) AS
SELECT 1, 'For Heaven only knows why anyone loves it so, how one sees it so, making it up, building it round one, tumbling it, creating it every moment afresh' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras ultricies vulputate turpis non porta. Pellentesque ex est, ultricies sed diam et, pulvinar sollicitudin sapien. Integer dignissim eu nulla vel eleifend. Vestibulum in orci placerat, volutpat urna vitae, eleifend enim. Suspendisse vitae fermentum nisl. Ut vitae ante faucibus, posuere ligula ut, bibendum purus. Vivamus dictum nunc vel nisl convallis, ut sollicitudin magna posuere. Duis et ante porttitor, iaculis purus id, porta eros. Donec at sapien metus. Aenean tellus ante, efficitur id metus ac, ullamcorper pharetra augue.' FROM DUAL

Both output:



ID
TEXT
LVL




1
For Heaven only knows why
1


1
anyone loves it so, how one
2


1
sees it so, making it up,
3


1
building it round one,
4


1
tumbling it, creating it every
5


1
moment afresh
6


2
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
1


2
consectetur adipiscing elit.
2


2
Cras ultricies vulputate
3


2
turpis non porta. Pellentesque
4


2
ex est, ultricies sed diam et,
5


2
pulvinar sollicitudin sapien.
6


2
Integer dignissim eu nulla vel
7


2
eleifend. Vestibulum in orci
8


2
placerat, volutpat urna vitae,
9


2
eleifend enim. Suspendisse
10


2
vitae fermentum nisl. Ut vitae
11


2
ante faucibus, posuere ligula
12


2
ut, bibendum purus. Vivamus
13


2
dictum nunc vel nisl
14


2
convallis, ut sollicitudin
15


2
magna posuere. Duis et ante
16


2
porttitor, iaculis purus id,
17


2
porta eros. Donec at sapien
18


2
metus. Aenean tellus ante,
19


2
efficitur id metus ac,
20


2
ullamcorper pharetra augue.
21




If you want it as columns then PIVOT:
WITH data (id, value) AS (
  SELECT id,
         value || ' '
  FROM   table_name
),
find (id, value, lvl, epos, text) AS (
  SELECT id,
         value,
         1,
         CASE
         WHEN INSTR(SUBSTR(value, 1, 31), ' ', -1) >= 1
         THEN 1 + INSTR(SUBSTR(value, 1, 31), ' ', -1)
         ELSE -1
         END,
         CASE
         WHEN INSTR(SUBSTR(value, 1, 31), ' ', -1) >= 1
         THEN SUBSTR(value, 1, INSTR(SUBSTR(value, 1, 31), ' ', -1) - 1)
         ELSE NULL
         END
  FROM   data
UNION ALL
  SELECT id,
         value,
         lvl + 1,
         CASE
         WHEN INSTR(SUBSTR(value, epos, 31), ' ', -1) >= 1
         THEN epos + INSTR(SUBSTR(value, epos, 31), ' ', -1)
         ELSE -1
         END,
         CASE
         WHEN INSTR(SUBSTR(value, epos, 31), ' ', -1) >= 1
         THEN SUBSTR(value, epos, INSTR(SUBSTR(value, epos, 31), ' ', -1) - 1)
         ELSE NULL
         END
  FROM   find
  WHERE  epos > -1
  AND    lvl  < 4
)
SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY id SET order_id
SELECT *
FROM   ( SELECT id, text, lvl FROM find )
       PIVOT (
         MAX(text)
         FOR lvl IN (
           1 AS first30,
           2 AS second30,
           3 AS third30,
           4 AS fourth30
         )
       );

or:
WITH data (id, value) AS (
  SELECT id,
         value || ' '
  FROM   table_name
),
find (id, value, lvl, epos, text) AS (
  SELECT id,
         value,
         1,
         REGEXP_INSTR(value, '(.{0,30}) ', 1, 1, 1),
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, '(.{0,30}) ', 1, 1, NULL, 1)
  FROM   data
UNION ALL
  SELECT id,
         value,
         lvl + 1,
         REGEXP_INSTR(value, '(.{0,30}) ', epos, 1, 1),
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, '(.{0,30}) ', epos, 1, NULL, 1)
  FROM   find
  WHERE  epos > 0
  AND    lvl  < 4
)
SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY id SET order_id
SELECT *
FROM   ( SELECT id, text, lvl FROM find )
       PIVOT (
         MAX(text)
         FOR lvl IN (
           1 AS first30,
           2 AS second30,
           3 AS third30,
           4 AS fourth30
         )
       );

Which both output:



ID
FIRST30
SECOND30
THIRD30
FOURTH30




1
For Heaven only knows why
anyone loves it so, how one
sees it so, making it up,
building it round one,


2
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
consectetur adipiscing elit.
Cras ultricies vulputate
turpis non porta. Pellentesque



fiddle

You can append a space to the end of the string and then match sub-strings of between 0 and 30 characters that are followed by a space. I.e. (.{0,30}) . Then repeat the pattern and take the last sub-group for subsequent matches:
SELECT id,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(
         value || ' ',
         '^(.{0,30}) ',
         1, 1, NULL, 1
       ) AS first30,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(
         value || ' ',
         '^(.{0,30} ){1}(.{0,30}) ',
         1, 1, NULL, 2
       ) AS second30,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(
         value || ' ',
         '^(.{0,30} ){2}(.{0,30}) ',
         1, 1, NULL, 2
       ) AS third30,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(
         value || ' ',
         '^(.{0,30} ){3}(.{0,30}) ',
         1, 1, NULL, 2
       ) AS fourth30
FROM   table_name;

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (id, value) AS
SELECT 1, 'For Heaven only knows why anyone loves it so, how one sees it so, making it up, building it round one, tumbling it, creating it every moment afresh' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras ultricies vulputate turpis non porta. Pellentesque ex est, ultricies sed diam et, pulvinar sollicitudin sapien. Integer dignissim eu nulla vel eleifend. Vestibulum in orci placerat, volutpat urna vitae, eleifend enim. Suspendisse vitae fermentum nisl. Ut vitae ante faucibus, posuere ligula ut, bibendum purus. Vivamus dictum nunc vel nisl convallis, ut sollicitudin magna posuere. Duis et ante porttitor, iaculis purus id, porta eros. Donec at sapien metus. Aenean tellus ante, efficitur id metus ac, ullamcorper pharetra augue.' FROM DUAL

Outputs:



ID
FIRST30
SECOND30
THIRD30
FOURTH30




1
For Heaven only knows why
anyone loves it so, how one
sees it so, making it up,
building it round one,


2
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
consectetur adipiscing elit.
Cras ultricies vulputate
turpis non porta. Pellentesque



fiddle
